# iPhone prototyping tools

Tags: iphone, prototyping

could anyone suggest some good (either free or commercial, web-based or desktop) iPhone / iPad apps prototyping tool?

I'm interested in creating app mockups aimed to both supporting design + development and displaying app stubs in business plans.

Thanks.

Comment: One good tool is Moqups (http://moqups.com). Minimal but awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these Links,

http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/21-prototyping-mockup-wireframing-tools-iphone-app-development/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228247/what-are-possible-good-ways-to-prototype-iphone-applications

http://lesscode.co.nz/interface

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you have Xcode 4.2 try the built-in storyboarding tool.
[Storyboard documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPad, check out [AppCooker](http://www.appcooker.com/). I've been using it recently and it is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

The one I use is [AppCooker](http://appcooker.com). It runs only on the iPad but is fun to use and you can run the prototype right away. 
The simpliest you can use is MS PowerPoint but it is very low fidelity. There is also Sketch Flow from Microsoft that goes along with MS Expression Blend.

Answer (score 0):

I made few tools for mobile wireframing - iPhone Wireframe Kit - Google Docs (free) http://www.vcarrer.com/2010/09/iphone-wireframe-kit-google-docs.html and Photoshop Wireframing Kit http://www.photoshopwireframingkit.com/ (commercial) I hope this tools can help you.